# Spring Security OAuth2 connect resource server to authorization server url with host and port

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am new for **Spring Security OAuth2**, I want to implement separate  **resource server** and **authorization server** so any one tell me that how **resource server** will **connect** to **authorization server** using **Host/IP address** or **Port**?

Answer (score 0):

You should design a API gateway server to centralize API connection.

So **resource  servers** would like to use **OAuth2** to get token and it should be connecting via API server.

You can use: [Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul.) for API gateway and [Eureka](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka) for locating services